# Assign integers to alphabets and add those integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to assign numbers 1-26 to alphabets a-z and add up those numbers according to any given string without any success. For example: `a = 1, b=2, c=3`. So, if any given string is `"abc"`, the output should be `1+2+3=6`.

Programming background - Novice, self-learning.
I have only learned upto strings, lists and their corresponding methods in python programming. I haven't studied functions and classes yet, so please make your answers as simple as possible.

So far I've tried

```
Name = "abc" 
a,b,c = [1,2,3]
Sum_of_name = ""
For alphabet in abc:
         Sum_of_name = sum_of_name + alphabet
Print(sum_of_name)
```

Prints out the same abc.

I realise that when I iterate the string "abc", the string is different than the variables a,b and c. Thus, the integers aren't assigned to the strings and can't be added up.

Any suggestions on how I can work through this with my current level of knowledge.

Comment: That's not even syntactically legal Python code (you can't capitalize `for`); even without the syntax error, you can't add strings and integers. Please provide a real [MCVE] (including actual errors, not just saying "without success").

Comment: Consider using [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead of lists e.g. `{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}`

Comment: Sorry for that For..I am typing in my phone so forgot about the capital F...ok..I will edit my posts for errors...

Comment: In programming, we have a mapping between letters and numbers already, called the [*ASCII table*](https://www.asciitable.com/). ASCII is a basic encoding that specifies numbers for characters. An example is the uppercase letter `A` being `65`. You can use this in Python using the `ord` builtin. For example, `ord('A')` returns 65. With a little bit of math...`ord('B') - ord('A') + 1 == 2`. How can you use that? `def uppercase_position(letter): ord(letter) - ord('A') + 1` would give you the capital letter's position in the alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
d = {v: i for i,v in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 1)}
Name = "abc" 
print( sum(d[i] for i in Name) )
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Comment: Minor improvement: Don't use `dict` constructor + genexpr, just use a dict comprehension. `d = {v: i for i,v in enumerate(string.lowercase, 1)}`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Can I know the reason please?

Comment: Like I said, it's a minor improvement, but `dict` comprehensions are essentially a faster, slightly more readable way of doing what you're doing with `dict()` + genexpr (in fact, the implementation is essentially a genexpr that replaces the `yield` step of a genexpr with a dedicated bytecode used for building dictionaries). Your approach is fine (and necessary if you need the code to work on Python 2.6 or earlier; `dict` comprehensions were added in 2.7), it's just a little more verbose and a little slower. The "why" is the same reason you use listcomps instead of `list()` + genexpr.

Comment: Thanks @rakesh ..as I ve written in the post above..my current level of knowledge doesn't cover dictionaries..any other simple alternatives? I appreciate your suggestion though..

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Thanks :)

Comment: @mathlover92: `dict`s are a *very* basic part of Python; I'd strongly recommend getting a basic familiarity with them. The only other reasonable solution to your problem involves the `zip` function with a hardcoded list of ordinal values (in which case `Name` isn't really needed), or manually mucking about with the `ord` function followed by ASCII math, both of which are uglier concepts than simple `dict` usage.

Comment: @Rakesh: Oh, and sorry, one more minor tweak: If the goal is to allow unrecognized characters to be silently replaced with `0`, you need to use `d.get(i, 0)`, not `d.get(i)` (which would return `None` for unrecognized characters and end up raising `TypeError`). If the goal is to have an exception, it's faster/simpler to just do `sum(d[i] for i in Name)` and let the `KeyError` propagate directly (`TypeError`s involving `NoneType` are more confusing than `KeyError`s informing you of a missing key in the `dict`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First make a list of the letters

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
>>> alphabet
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Then make a lookup of letter to value (there are other ways to do this)

```
>>> values = {letter: value for value, letter in enumerate(alphabet, 1)}
>>> values
{'d': 4, 'f': 6, 'o': 15, 'b': 2, 's': 19, 'c': 3, 'w': 23, 'q': 17, 'v': 22, 'p': 16, 'i': 9, 'e': 5, 'l': 12, 't': 20, 'y': 25, 'n': 14, 'a': 1, 'r': 18, 'j': 10, 'x': 24, 'g': 7, 'm': 13, 'k': 11, 'h': 8, 'z': 26, 'u': 21}
```

Then use that to `sum` values

```
def sum_letters(word):
    return sum(values[letter] for letter in word)

>>> sum_letters('abc')
6
```

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer for your suggestion..but I haven't yet started learning defining functions like you defined sum_letters(word).

Comment: Well now you have :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed order then you can use ord()

```
a="Name"
s=0
for i in a.lower():
     s+=ord(i)-96
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the characters in the alphabet, you can use the `string` lib:

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = string.lowercase
>>> letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

We can then turn that into a dictionary to make getting the numeric (positional) value of a letter easy:

```
letter_map = dict(zip(list(letters), range(1, len(letters) + 1)))
```

So your function will perform a simple dict lookup for each letter input:

```
def string_sum(string_input):
    return sum(letter_map[char] for char in string_input)
```

Several test cases:

```
>>> assert string_sum('abc') == 6
>>> assert string_sum('') == 0  # because it's empty
```